# Mysql query taking 50 seconds

Tags: php, mysql

The table reuniao (EN: meeting), has 401000 records, and it has an index on all columns, im using XAMPP, and 
I think the problems are on trying to do an ORDER BY on a COUNT and the Join, but 50 seconds its to much.

Columns, nome its varchar (EN: Name), presenca its varchar (EN: presence), partido its varchar (EN: political party), id_deputado its PK INT, and data (its Date).

```
SELECT D.nome, COUNT(*) as count_dep_faltas 
FROM reuniao R, deputado D 
WHERE R.partido LIKE '%$_POST[partido]%' AND 
R.presenca LIKE '%Injustific%' AND 
data BETWEEN '$data_incio' AND '$data_fim' and 
R.id_deputado=D.id_deputado 
GROUP BY D.nome 
ORDER BY count_dep_faltas DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Also parameterize that query, don't put `POST` in a query, you are open to injections with this approach.

Comment: I'm curious as to where one gets 400k worth of records and doesn't know what to do with it or knows how to handle it properly.

Comment: You have your reasons, its for a school work about web scrapping, and one of the requirements its gather all the dataset

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, written using proper `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT D.nome, COUNT(*) as count_dep_faltas
FROM deputado D JOIN
     reuniao R
     ON R.id_deputado = D.id_deputado
WHERE R.partido LIKE '%$_POST[partido]%' AND
      R.presenca LIKE '%Injustific%' AND
      R.data BETWEEN '$data_incio' AND '$data_fim'
GROUP BY D.nome
ORDER BY count_dep_faltas DESC;
LIMIT 5;
```

First, you need to learn to use parameters for passing in queries, rather than munging the query string.  This prevents unexpected syntax errors and SQL injection.  But that is not related to performance.

This is hard to optimize in MySQL because of the wildcards in the `LIKE` patterns.  You can approach this by creating an index on `reuniao(data, partido, presenca, id_deputado)` and `deputado(id_deputado, nome)`.  This is a covering index, so it should have some improvement.

I would also recommend that you consider full text indexes, if you really need matches on the strings with wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i tried the query but it still takes 50s, i have an index B-TREE on all columns of reuniao, perhaps using HASH?, and MySQL automatically assigned a B-TREE on the two columns of deputado (id_deputado,nome), but i can create one

Comment: @VoltDamage . . . You need to specific indexes referred to in the answer.  These are composite indexes with more than one column.